# can not get realmlist from realm object

Tags: android, realm

I have class TrackingInfo extends to RealmObject and it has realmList called  RealmList savedPath ..MySavedLatLng extends RealmObject now i want to get the object

```
    mRealm.allObjects(TrackingInfo.class);
    RealmResults<TrackingInfo> trackinresult =     mRealm.where(TrackingInfo.class).equalTo("order_id", order_id).findAll();

    if (!trackinresult.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = trackinresult.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            trackinresult.get(i);
            double getdistanation=trackinresult.get(i).getSavedDistance();
            double getduration=trackinresult.get(i).getSavedDuration();
            int getOrder_id=trackinresult.get(i).getOrder_id();
            RealmList<MySavedLatLng> getpath=trackinresult.get(i).getSavedPath();

            Log.e("data saved",getdistanation+""+getduration+""+getOrder_id+"" +getpath+"");
            Log.e("result", trackinresult.get(i) + "");
        }
```

I want to get latitude and longitude from MySavedLatLng object !!
how can i do it ?
thanx..

Comment: `allObjects` in Realm-Java was removed in 0.91.0,  and replaced with `realm.where().findAll()`. What version of Realm is this?

Comment: but i use realm.findall();
i use this version of realm
        compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.4'

Comment: Well if everything is set up right, then you just need to treat the RealmList as a list. Any reason why you never updated to at least 0.88.3, but preferably to 1.2.0?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what the problem is. Why doesn't the above code work?

Comment: Assuming that trackinresult.get(i).getSavedPath() is not null, just iterate the list and extract the values....or try to better explain your issue